# jQuery with fancybox using trigger() cause stack overflow

Tags: jquery, triggers, fancybox, stack-overflow

I am trying to open fancybox image gallery (with thumbnails) by clicking on element which is not really related to the fancybox gallery, so I want to use triger method.

Problem is, that with the greater amount of photos (8 galleries with 10 pics/each gal for instance) if causes stack overflow. I found few answers here, such asi using live(), bind(), stopPropagation(), stopImmediatePropagation() etc, but nothing seems to work for me.

HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="thumb_1" class="fancy-thumb">
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" id="gal-1 rel="gal-1"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-1"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-1"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  .........
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-1"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-1"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <another html elements absolute positioned such as labels etc>
</div>
.........
<div id="thumb_10" class="fancy-thumb">
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" id="gal-10 rel="gal-10"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-10"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-10"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  .........
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-10"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gal-10"><img src="./foo/bar.baz"/></a>
  <another html elements absolute positioned such as labels etc>
</div>
```

and JS looks like this:

```
// fancybox is initialized in after document ready
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox();

// this function should trigger fancybox
this.openGal(e){
   var gal_id = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
   $("#" + gal_id).trigger("click");
   return false;
   // note that here I've tried almost everything found at stackoverflow
   // but nothing seems to work
}

// listeren looks like this
$(".fancy-thumb").click(function(e) {scope.openGal(e);});
```

Please, do not post such answers that is should do it in standart way and that using trigger() is not an good idea. I need to use trigger().

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r9SEs/ is a fiddle I made, please edit it to be more correct, I added in some dummy alerts to help, I also found some id tags quotes weren't closed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can see only first alert, that which is triggered right after click, but not that second one, inside openGal function

Comment: So I have edited the fiddle, The trigger calls fancythumbs click function resulting in an infinite loop, I am guessing this is what is happening in your code. I will add an answer with this and try to find a solution. Can you post more code/ relevance to why you are doing things this way?

Comment: Just for the record: the container `div` shouldn't have the class `fancy-thumb`, just the anchors inside of it, otherwise fancybox will try to launch with the content of the `div` as well as the target of the clicked anchor (the solution could have been simpler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openGal(e){
   var gal_id = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
   $("#" + gal_id).trigger("click");  //this was causing the following function to be called, resulting in an infinite loop
   return false;
}

// by delegating down a level, we are at the elements we actually want to attack
// the '>' operator selects child elements
$(".fancy-thumb >").click(function(e) {
    openGal(e);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LsmVb/ shows how the alerts will be called correctly, by changing `$(".fancy-thumb a")` to `$(".fancy-thumb")` you can see where the infinite loop arose.

You will also want to wrap an enclosing div tag inside of the content of your fancy-thumbs, this will allow the above operator to select it. If you don't want to do this, all text not enclosed in a tag will not be clickable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem is, that I cant use $(".fancy-thumb a").click() but $(".fancy-thumb").click(), because there are some things as labels etc over the <a> as I wrote in my original post, so I need whole .fancy-thumb div to be clickable, which is, if I understood well, impossible to do due to infinite loop?

Comment: @Meph sorry, forgot about that. Check new edit and see if this helps (:

Comment: I got "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: > "

Comment: What browser? http://jsfiddle.net/LsmVb/ is working for me on ff and chrome (I forked it)?

Comment: Chrome Version 21.0.1180.89 on OSX Lion, using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js

Comment: It seems it is because of old jquery version. Your JS fiddle is woking fine. I will try to change it and I will let you know. I very appreciate your help!

Comment: Now it "works", but fancybox is not opened - "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Ok, so finally I figured out..I added another element one the same level where the links are which is all over everything else and it just works. Thanks for your time!